# How to use document.getElementById in inline click event binding?

Tags: javascript, angular

The following code cannot be parsed by VS Code.

> Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 34 in
> [(document.getElementById('btnA') as HTMLInputElement).disabled=true]
> in

```
<button id="btnA">A</button>
<button (click)="(document.getElementById('btnA') as HTMLInputElement).disabled=true">Disable A</button>
```

or

```
<button id="btnA">A</button>
<button (click)="<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('btnA').disabled=true">Disable A</button>
```

How to use `document.getElementById()` in *inline click event bindin*g?

## Edit 1:

I want to use event binding rather than `onclick`.

## Edit 2:

Actually I want to mimic the working code below but with `getElementById()`.

```
<button #btnA>A</button>
<button (click)="btnA.disabled=true">Disable A</button>
```

Comment: in the fisrt, you should remove the "(". NOTE: Yes, the "Angular way" is to use a variable

Comment: `Yes. I did but I want to know how to make it with getElementById` -> Why? Angular exposes a lot of *good* ways to manipulate DOM, and doing it using javascript is a bad practice, since you are exiting the scope of Angular itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template reference, which will be a reference to the HTML element

```html
<button #btnA>A</button>
<button (click)="btnA.disabled=true">Disable A</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button id="btnA">A</button>
<button onClick="() =>{<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('btnA').disabled=false"}>Disable A</button>
```

Comment: Sorry. I want to use event binding.

Comment: AFAIK this is event binding: [What does event binding even mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6329996/463206); perhaps the OP means to use the [DOM elements' addEventListener`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Comment: Event binding (and other bindings) in Angular: https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax